# Apache Spark: Error to run the command to read file from HDFS

Tags: apache-spark

I have tried to use to load file from HDFS but I cannot use the command map reduce.

My command to count word in a file:

```
sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/darkntnt/input/zip_codes.csv")
  .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(word => (word,1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)
```

Error :

```
   java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/user/darkntnt/input/zip_codes.csv
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$defaultPartitioner$2.apply(Partitioner.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$defaultPartitioner$2.apply(Partitioner.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:331)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:331)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:330)
  ... 48 elided
```

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can read a file

```
text1 = sc.textFile('hdfs:///project1/filename.txt')
text2 = sc.textFile('hdfs://localhost:port/user/filename.txt')
text3 = sc.textFile('localpath/filename.txt')
```

Option: Use HUE or other tool to get the full path.